# interapolation of missing values

Tags: python, interpolation, missing-data

I am trying to interpolate the missing values by linear method in python dataframe. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output ?

Comment: I can only think of for loop :-(

Comment: @WeNYoBen can you share how can you do in for loop?

Comment: @WeNYoBen can you share how can you do in for loop?

Comment: One question how you get the 24 at column D

Comment: @WeNYoBen sorry about that. I have changed the column D values

Comment: If you just run single interpolate for columns D the first missing value should be 184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, I'm not sure the best one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [12, 4, 5, None, 1],
                   "B": [None, 2, 10000, 20000, None],
                   "C": [1, None, None, 8, None],
                   "D": [14, 99, None, None, 6]})


l = df.columns
for i in l:
    for j in range(len(df[i])):
        if j > 1 and pd.isna(df[i].iloc[j]):
            m = -1
            for k in range(j - 1, -1, -1):
                if not pd.isna(df[i].iloc[k]):
                    if m == -1:
                        m = k
                    else:
                        df[i].iloc[j] = df[i].iloc[m] + ((df[i].iloc[m] - 
 df[i].iloc[k]) / (m - k)) * (j - m)
                        break
print(df)
```

out:

```
      A        B          C      D
0  12.0      NaN   1.000000   14.0
1   4.0      2.0        NaN   99.0
2   5.0  10000.0        NaN  184.0
3   6.0  20000.0   8.000000  269.0
4   1.0  30000.0  10.333333    6.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The `C` column should use the two available previous values and generate the last row.

Comment: The method is linear but in an easy way. just `s[i]=s[i-1]*2 - s[i-2]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer to interpolate using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html). Code below using Python 3.7:

**Import libraries**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Create a DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x':[0, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 6, np.nan, 10],
'y':[0, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6, np.nan, 8, np.nan, 20]
})
```

**Interpolate missing or NaN values: linear**

```
df['ix'] = df['x'].interpolate(method='linear')
df['iy'] = df['y'].interpolate(method='linear')
```

**Create plot of with interpolated values**

```
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], label='original') 
plt.scatter(df['ix'],df['iy'], marker='o', facecolor='none', color='red', s=200, label='interpolated')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Original data with linear-interpolated data')
```

[image: plot with interpolated data]